# What is the best way to store checkbox information?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have an activity with `listview` of `checkboxes`, as you can see on the photo below:

Also, user can add as many items as he wants by clicking add other button. If the user goes to another activity, and then again goes to this one, the `checkboxes` need to appear in the way the user had saved it. I used shared preferences to save the ones are checked and not checked. But the list can become really long, so is it better to use anything else?

[image]

Comment: Make use of Model.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `ListView`.  
This means you already have some kind of `ArrayList` where you store the labels: FirstItem, SecondItem, ... and Description as I see. 
In this ListView's adapter create a Boolean field say isChecked and store in it the state of each checkbox.    
So the adapter will hold 3 fields instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

If list can be long and you need to recreate it every time when opening it again it is better to store this data in some Local DB like [room persistence library](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/). 
`SharedPreferences` designed for storing small amount of data like in your case info about one particular item.